# How to get the variance between two arrays?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, variance, distance, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,4],[2,4,8]])
np.var(a)

output: 5.25
```

Can anyone enlight me what's the calculation process to get variance = 5.25?

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html?highlight=numpy%20var#numpy.var) says:

> The variance is the average of the squared deviations from the mean, i.e., var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)

and

> The variance is computed for the flattened array by default

This means that Numpy is not computing the variance between two arrays, but the variance of one array which is [1,2,4,2,4,8].

Note that this is by default the *biased* sample variance ($\tilde{s}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum \limits_{i=1}^N (x_i - \overline{x})^2$) while other statistics software (e.g., R) might give you the *unbiased* sample variance by default ($s^2 = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum \limits_{i=1}^N (x_i - \overline{x})^2$).